# How to lock phone like shutdown in android?

Tags: android

Now I'm coding in android. When I press the button that shutdowns the phone, i want to shutdown the phone like *turn off the screen* or *don't use the phone* until the time that I set.

My scenario is this.

1. I press the button and set time (6:00 - 12:00) - in 6:00~12:00, the phone shutdowns.
2. The phone shutdowns.
3. if It's time to 12:00, the phone comes back (All functions are available)

Can I control the phone screen or control not to use the phone?

Comment: where is your code?

Answer (score 0):

It is not possible for you to close the android device. Even `Intent.ACTION_SHUTDOWN` is thrown after the shutdown dialog and is just for informing other applications (intent does not actually start the shutdown sequence).

You can check `ShutdownThread` https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base/+/a029ea1/services/java/com/android/server/power/ShutdownThread.java